# How use dynamic variable without missing ] after element list?

Tags: javascript, dynamic-variables

I have a dynamic variable like this:

```
var oneButton= null;
var oneMoreButton= null;
var differentNameButton= null;
var anotherButtonDifferent= null;
```

Then i have this:

```
switch(valor){
    case 0:data = "oneButton"; break;
    case 1:data = "oneMoreButton";break;
    case 2:data = "differentNameButton";break;
    case 3:data = "anotherButtonDifferent";break;
}
```

Then finally i have this:

```
switch(anotherValor){           
case 1:eval(data + ' = ' + document.getElementById('oneNameDiv').parentNode);break;
case 2:eval(data + ' = ' + document.getElementById('anotherDivName').parentNode);break;
case 3:eval(data + ' = ' + document.getElementById('oneMoreDivWithDifferentName').parentNode);break;
case 4:eval(data + ' = ' + document.getElementById('hereIsAnotherDivName').parentNode);break;
}
```

After i try to execute it i get the error in firefox console:

```
missing ] after element list
http://localhost:8090/myapplication/functions.js 
test1 = [objectHTMLDivElement]
```

Someone knows what's happening?

Comment: Ever heard of a data structure, called `Array`?

Comment: In global, what are you trying to do?

Comment: im not using array to simplify... im not using something like array[x] because i cant do this... what im trying to do is exactly what i've exaplined.... i have the some variables that i've declared before... then i need to put a div into each variable...

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what exactly you are trying to achieve, but your code could be better. Something like this for example:

```
var data = document.getElementById('div'+valor).parentNode;
```

Assuming there is a variable called valor with the number of your div.

Could you explain what you are doing?

Comment: no its another variable... not the same... well, i need to ordenate a couple of buttons by an user interaction... And i need to save the state of the buttons if he open the modal again. then i save it in an array... i need to get the div of the buttons dinamicly... the first 'valor' is to determinate wich button i am getting, the second one is the value of which button should i take at that momment..

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an array like this:

```
var test = [];
```

Then you can use "valor" directly:

```
test[valor]
```